# How to capture audio output on macOS using Python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, real-time

I would like to capture output directly from the speakers to make a real time audio visualizer. Is there a way to do it using python? I tried using the  [Realtime_PyAudio_FFT by aiXander](https://github.com/aiXander/Realtime_PyAudio_FFT)

(I am using MacOS and I have MacBook with M2 if that might help)

Comment: https://github.com/aiXander/Realtime_PyAudio_FFT

Comment: https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole